# How to find correct port in linux and specify it in platformio

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, microcontroller, avr

So I'm currently having trouble with selecting the correct upload port in the platformio extension using VS Code. PIO is automatically detecting /dev/ttyS0 as port which is not correct and produces a timeout error when used. For programming the PCB, I'm using an Atmel AVRISP mkII which is connected via USB to my PC.

upload settings in platformio.ini:

```
upload_protocol = custom
upload_port = usb
upload_flags =
    -C
    $PROJECT_PACKAGES_DIR/tool-avrdude/avrdude.conf
    -p
    $BOARD_MCU
    -P
    $UPLOAD_PORT
    -c
    stk500v2
    -e
upload_command = avrdude $UPLOAD_FLAGS -U flash:w:$SOURCE:i`
```

The programmer is recognized:

```
lsusb -d 03eb:2104
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 03eb:2104 Atmel Corp. AVR ISP mkII

ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/013 
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 189, 12  3月 31 14:03 /dev/bus/usb/001/013
```

and is mapped to the following path:

```
ls -l /sys/dev/char/189:12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0  3月 31 13:56 /sys/dev/char/189:12 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9
```

However I cant use `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/` as port since it's a directory. So which path do I need to specify, so that PIO uploads to the correct port?
Ubuntu 22.10.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally on Linux connections over USB to embedded devices are handled over the "enhanced" ports `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyACM1` (generally you get the first, but if you unplug/re-plug too quickly for the first port to reset you get the second)

Comment: It also shows up in the dmesg or in the syslog after connecting the usb device.